# Load the Specific database value to the Listbox in HTML

Tags: php, html

I have developed a Sign up page in php and there is a listbox (combobox) in the registration page to choose cities.Asume a user registered with choosing New York in the listbox. Now the New York value is stored in the database.My question is I want to give the user a profile page where he can edit his last values.So when the profile page load I want to load the listbox with the New York value which get from he database. (Keep in mind I don't want to add a new value to the list box. Just want to get the previously inserted value to be selected when page loads.)How can I do this.Can some one help me.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `selected` attribute to the `<option>` element that matches the data in the database. The easiest way to do this, generally, is to generate the options by looping over an array of all the possible values.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you render your cities, so I'm going to make some assumptions and leave it to you to figure out how to adapt it to your code

```
$user_city = 'New York';

$cities = [
    'Texas',
    'New York',
    'Arizona',
    'Washington'
];

echo '<select>';

foreach($cities as $city){
    echo '<option '.($city == $user_city ? 'selected' : null).'>'.$city.'</option>';
}

echo '</select>';
```

And also you should work with ids, instead of names as I have done in the example.

Comment: opps sorry it should be cities. I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it working. Thank you for helping. Here is what I did

$user_city  is the value I am getting from the database.

```
<select name="area" id="area" style="border:"><optgroup label="cities">
        <option value="New York"
        <?php if($user_city=='New York'){echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>New
            York</option>
        <option value="Texas"
        <?php if($user_city =='Texas'){echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>Texas</option>
        <option value="Arizona"
        <?php if($user_city =='Arizona'){echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>Arizona</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```